# linux pipes and buffers, not sure how to get the loop to work

Tags: c, linux, pipe, system-calls

I'm writing a DB program in C for a Unix class I'm taking. While I've managed to get all the pipes, buffers, and commands to work, the while loops are throwing ME for a loop. The program will execute the first command completely fine, take in a second command, but then promptly quit. I've loaded it with error checking and nothing is thrown, so the mechanics are fine but there's a logic issue somewhere in the loop that I cannot identify.

Here's the repository: https://gitlab.com/IrateSwami/c_pipes/tree/dev

Example run:

```
1234567 102 08/11/18 4.00
1234567 101 08/14/18 14.00
3456787 9873 08/30/18 100.00
1234567 100 08/16/18 35.00
3456787 9874 09/30/18 4.00
12345 1010 09/01/18 34.00
1001001 905 08/14/18 9.00
1001001 903 08/30/18 11.00
12345 1001 09/14/18 16.00
12345 1111 08/24/18 2.00
12345 1112 08/31/18 44.00
1001001 902 09/25/18 19.00

Enter a command: add,1234567,999,01/01/01,99.99

Enter a command: list
```

The do while that's giving me trouble from the slave.c file:

```
// start the do-while loop for command stuff

// read in from the pipe
error_check = read(read_pipe, buffer, 1000);
if(error_check<0){
    perror("child process error, reading in from pipe");
    exit(-3);
}

// null terminate the end of buffer 
buffer[error_check] = '\0';

// here's where the command stuff starts 
char *first_command;
while(strcmp(first_command, "exit\n") != 0){
    // grab the first thing from the buffer, it'll be the command
    char *command = strtok(buffer, ",");
    first_command = command;
    printf("first command: %s\n", first_command);


    // now for the parameters
    int parameter_count = 0;
    char *parameters[4];

    while(command != NULL){
        command = strtok(NULL, ",");
        parameters[parameter_count] = command;
        parameter_count++;
    }

    // exit appropriately
    if(strcmp(first_command, "exit\n") == 0)
        return 9;

    // add a record
    else if(strcmp(first_command, "add") == 0){
        Record temp_record;
        temp_record.account_number = atoi(parameters[0]);
        temp_record.check_number = atoi(parameters[1]);
        temp_record.amount = atof(parameters[3]);
        strcmp(temp_record.transaction_date, parameters[2]);

        records[record_count] = temp_record;
        record_count++;

        error_check = write(write_pipe, "add completed", strlen(buffer));
        if(error_check<0){
            perror("error writing in add function");
            exit(-6);
        }
    }

    // delete a record
    else if(strcmp(first_command, "delete") == 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < record_count; i++){
            if(
            atoi(parameters[0]) == records[i].account_number && 
            atoi(parameters[1]) == records[i].check_number){

                records[i].account_number = 0;
                records[i].check_number = 0;
                records[i].amount = 0.0;
                strcpy(records[i].transaction_date, "\0");

            }
        }
    }

    // list all the records contained
    else if(strcmp(first_command, "list\n") == 0){

        // write all the records to the buffer 
        position = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < record_count; i++){
            position += sprintf(buffer+position, "%d %d %s %.2f\n", 
            records[i].account_number,
            records[i].check_number,
            records[i].transaction_date,
            records[i].amount);
        }

        printf("%s\n", buffer);

        // write the buffer to the pipe
        error_check = write(write_pipe, buffer, strlen(buffer));

        // check for errors
        if(error_check<0){
            perror("child process write error");
            exit(-4);
        }

        // make sure the length of the buffer was proper
        if(error_check!=strlen(buffer)){
            printf("child process error, buffer was a weird size\n");
            exit(-5);
        }
    }

    else{
        printf("you didn't input a correct command\n");
    }


    // empty out everything for reuse
    strcpy(buffer, "\0");
    command = "\0";
    first_command = "\0";
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        parameters[i] = "\0";

    // grab the new command 
    error_check = read(read_pipe, buffer, 1000);
    if(error_check<0){
        perror("child process error, reading in from pipe");
        exit(-5);
    }

    // null terminate the end of buffer 
    buffer[error_check] = '\0';

    printf("end of child do while buffer: %s\n", buffer);

}
```

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. We don't want the full code, reduce it to a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: @Barmar done! Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You don't set `first_command` until you get inside the `while` loop.

Comment: You should put `\n` in the delimiter list of `strtok()` so you don't need to include it in your `strcmp()` calls.

Comment: There's no need to test `first_command` in the `while` condition, just use `while(1)`. You `return` when the user enters `exit`, so you'll never get back to the test in that case.

Comment: All the `"\0"` strings should just be `""`. String literals automatically get a null terminator, you don't have to add it explicitly.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious that's causing the loop to break when you enter the second command. Have you tried running the program under a debugger to see what's happening?

Comment: That's not a [mcve]. For one, it's incomplete; there isn't even a `main`.

Comment: What do you mean by "promptly quit"? Any error message? You are just showing what you put into the pipe. Please, add the program output to your question. Also add what is sent back to the pipe by your program.

Comment: @xhienne the "promptly quit" part is demonstrated above in the example execution, immediately after entering "list", or any other argument, the program quits and returns to prompt

Comment: @Barmar have the while(1) seems to work, thank you

Comment: @BryanE You say "The program will execute the first command completely fine". If that was the case, you would have seen "first command: ..." and received "add completed". Moreover, you check a lot of return values, that's quite good, but you fail to check that `read` returns 0 (EOF => pipe empty and closed, which means child is dead). One last thing (for now): `records.transaction_date` is not large enough; it is supposed to contain an 8 character date plus the NUL string terminator.

Comment: @xhienne this is immensely helpful, I greatly appreciate you taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 1):

First, we can notice that what the child (slave) is supposed to output doesn't appear on screen after the first command (add ...) was sent to it.

At the second prompt for a command, if you stop your program and execute `ps` you'll notice that the child is dead:

```
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
27069 pts/29   00:00:00 master
27070 pts/29   00:00:00 slave <defunct>
```

One major problem in the slave is that your are comparing `first_command`, which is not initialized, to "exit". That comparison requires that the bytes at address `first_command` be accessed. If that address is NULL, or more generally outside your program space, you get a segmentation fault which kills the child.

How did this get unnoticed by the parent process? Because when you `read` from the pipe, you only check for errors, not for EOF (0) which means the pipe is empty and closed (IOW, the child is dead).

The fix: initialize your variable

```
char *first_command = "";
```

(or better, use a `do...while` loop)

There are other minor issues in your code, some having already been reported to you in comments, some appearing clearly when compiling with `-Wall` (always use that flag and fix the warnings), some other waiting for your sagacity ;-)